# Problemas no PM2 - NodeJS

Tags: javascript, linux, node.js

Estou com um problema no PM2 será que já aconteceu com alguém.

Eu dou start em algumas aplicações e eles aparecem normalmente na lista quando executo pm2 list. Porém após alguns dias as aplicações desaparecem do pm2 list.
Elas continuam funcionando mais só consigo acha-las quando executo ps aux | grep node, conforme imagem abaixo.

Já desinstalei o PM2 reinstalei o pior que isso acontece com mais de um servidor. Alguém tem alguma ideia?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Você tem algum código para fornecer? Talvez possa ajudar. Tenta finalizar todos os processos node e executar apenas pelo pm2.

Answer (score -1):

É comum de isso acontecer quando você executa o pm2 start como root e pm2 list como usuário comum ou vice-versa. Sempre execute sua aplicação como usuário e nunca como root.